# WebView and Javascript Interface problems with SherlockActionBar

Tags: javascript, actionbarsherlock, android-webview

I have a problem: when I use webview with javascript interface to comunication between my activity and the html page, my actionbarsherlock stop working. And the problem is in this line:

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsObject(), "injectedObject");
```

the problems include List navigations and menu items with ActionView .

Basically if I comment the above code, everything works normally.

Some pictures to explain:

My Activity with sherlockactionbar and webview
[image: My Activity with sherlockactionbar and webview]

My actionbar not working when when I'm calling the method **addJavascriptInterface** in my webview
[image: My actionbar not working when when I'm calling the method **addJavascriptInterface** in my webview]

My actionbar working when I remove the method **addJavascriptInterface**
[image: My actionbar working when I remove the method **addJavascriptInterface**]

How can I solve this problem???? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I figured out my problem looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898940/sherlock-actionbar-invalidateoptionsmenu)

Basically I had a method accessed by javascript that disguised a view. So this occasioned UI errors.

Before:

```
class JsObject {
   @JavascriptInterface
   public void cancelProgress() {
     progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
}
```

After:

```
class JsObject {
   @JavascriptInterface
   public void cancelProgress() {
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
     @Override
       public void run(){
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
   });
  }
}
```